# Sql query to fetch a single record from a multiple records grouped by a single column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Here is my dataset

```
Company  Sector
ABC      IT
ABC      FINANCE
XYZ      IT
```

Result expected   - Null if there is more than 1 sector

```
Company  Sector
ABC      NULL
XYZ      IT
```

Your help is much appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Company,  
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Sector) = 1 THEN MAX(Sector) END AS Sector
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Company
```